# Caching time period for glide in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, caching, android-glide

I want to know that how much time glide keeps images cached on the device. I've read the documentation of glide on https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html but didn't found the expected answer

Answer (score 0):

The glide cache is size bound:

> By default Glide uses the InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory class to build disk caches. The internal cache factory places the disk cache in your application's internal cache directory and sets a maximum size of 250MB.

See here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#disk-cache

You can also change the size of the data and memory cache if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, by default glide use 250 MB of space for storing cache in your device. which can be manipulated by

```
builder.setDiskCache(
  new ExternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, cacheDirectoryName, yourSizeInBytes));
```

Caches are either cleared by you manually or cleared by the system if the limit is reached. So you can assume that the time is until the decided storage limit is reached.